# No symbols inside a multilevel numbered list in Lyx

Tags: symbols, lists, numbering, lyx

I have some numbered lists in Lyx with 4 levels of indentation. On the first level there are numbers (1,2,3,....), on the second small letters ( (a),(b),(c),...), then Roman numbers (i, ii, iii,...) then capital letters (A,B,C,...).

I would like to remove all the symbols (letters, Roman numbers...) from the 2nd level on, or to substitute them with an unique symbol, such as "-". Is it possible to do so in Lyx?

Comment: Are you using `enumerate` to make the lists? You can use `itemize` lists instead to switch to symbols. An example of how you are making the list will be helpful in addressing the problem.

Comment: With no feedback, this is 'too localized'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List | Description` and then simply type a symbol you like, like a hyphen or mdash, and then a space, and you are there. Space alone (i.e. no symbol) does not work this way, though.